# How to modify string list for duplicate values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am working on project which is asp.net mvc core. I want to replace string list of duplicate values to one with comma separated,

```
List<string> stringList = surveylist.Split('&').ToList();
```

I have string list
This generate following output:

```
7=55
6=33
5=MCC
4=GHI
3=ABC
1003=DEF
1003=ABC
1=JKL
```

And I want to change output like this

```
7=55
6=33
5=MCC
4=GHI
3=ABC
1003=DEF,ABC
1=JKL
```

Duplicate items values should be comma separated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I tried this which i share, i dont know how to do it, i am new, please help

Comment: I suggest you first read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). People here respond negatively if your question gives them the impression that you're asking them to do your work for you.

Comment: Well by the way this is not home work question and i already told you i am new to stack overflow and also new to c# so i dont know how to do it, i am sure here are professional programmer and this one is easy question, please help me, i dont want to waste my more 5-10 hours again to try then again post here, i am trying from last 2-3 days please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably 20 ways to do this.  One simple one would be:

```
List<string> newStringList = stringList
  .Select(a => new { KeyValue = a.Split("=") })
  .GroupBy(a => a.KeyValue[0])
  .Select(a => $"{a.Select(x => x.KeyValue[0]).First()}={string.Join(",", a.Select(x => x.KeyValue[1]))}")
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks alot, very nice, clean and simple solution !!! You great man

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your output. Notice that an equal sign separates each string into a *key-value pair*. Think about how you want to approach this problem. Is a list of strings really the structure you want to build on? You could take a different approach and use a list of KeyValuePairs or a Dictionary instead.

If you really need to do it with a List, then look at the methods [LINQ's Enumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=net-7.0) has to offer. Namely `Select` and `GroupBy`.

You can use `Select` to split once more on the equal sign: `.Select(s => s.Split('='))`.

You can use `GroupBy` to group values by a key: `.GroupBy(pair => pair[0])`.

To join it back to a string, you can use a `Select` again.

An end result could look something like this:

```cs
List<string> stringList = values.Split('&')
    .Select(s => {
        string[] pair = s.Split('=');
        return new { Key = pair[0], Value = pair[1] };
    })
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.Key)
    .Select(g => string.Concat(
        g.Key,
        '=',
        string.Join(
            ", ",
            g.Select(pair => pair.Value)
        )
    ))
    .ToList();
```

The group contains pairs so you need to select the value of each pair and join them into a string.